# c# fetching database into SQL Server datatable

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have a problem with this code... I don't have the slightest clue for what is happening...

When I run this code in Visual Studio, I get an error saying:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.'

And here's the code:

```
conn.Open();

SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("update lend set date_back=convert(datetime2, getdate(), 102) where client_name ='" + comboBox1.Text + "'", conn);

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Declare @startdate smalldatetime declare @enddate smalldatetime set @startdate = (select date_lended from dbo.lend where client_name = '" + comboBox1.Text + "') set @enddate = (select date_back from dbo.lend where client_name = '" + comboBox1.Text + "') SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, @startdate+2, @enddate)as timepassedd", conn);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);

foreach (DataRow DR in dt.Rows)
{
    int date;
    date = Convert.ToInt32(DR["timepassedd"]);

    if (date > 0)
    {
        com = new SqlCommand("DELETE lend WHERE client_name ='"+comboBox1.Text+"'" +
                             "UPDATE book_list set book_stock = book_stock  1 WHERE book_name ='" + comboBox1.Text + "'",conn);
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show("You Returned the book " + date + " Days Late!" +
                            "please pay the fee to the front desk");

        UserPanel u = new UserPanel();
        u.Show();

        this.Hide();
    }
    else if (date <= 0)
    {
        com = new SqlCommand("DELETE lend WHERE client_name ='" + comboBox1.Text + "'" +
                             "UPDATE book_list set book_stock = book_stock  1 WHERE book_name ='" + comboBox1.Text + "'", conn);
        com.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show("You returned the book " + date + " Days Late!" +
                            "please pay the fee to the front desk");

        UserPanel u = new UserPanel();
        u.Show();

        this.Hide();
    }
}

conn.Close();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have allowed nulls in your database table, it can't convert null values, don't allow null values or use a datareader and check each bit of data that could be null with 'IsDBNull' and if it isn't null display other a default value

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("update lend set date_back=convert(datetime2, getdate(), 102) where client_name ='" + comboBox1.Text + "'", conn);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Declare @startdate smalldatetime declare @enddate smalldatetime set @startdate = (select date_lended from dbo.lend where client_name = '" + comboBox1.Text + "') set @enddate = (select date_back from dbo.lend where client_name = '" + comboBox1.Text + "') SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, @startdate+2, @enddate)as timepassedd", conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        if(ds.Tables.Count == 1)
        {
            if(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach(DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    if(dr.ItemArray.Length > 0)
                    {
                        if(dr["timepassedd"] != DBNull.Value)
                        {
                            int date;
                            date = Convert.ToInt32(Dr["timepassedd"]);
                            if (date > 0)
                            {
                                com = new SqlCommand("delete lend where client_name ='" + comboBox1.Text + "'" +
                                    "UPDATE book_list set book_stock = book_stock  1 WHERE book_name ='" + comboBox1.Text + "'", conn);
                                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                MessageBox.Show("You Returned the book " + date + " Days Late!" +
                                    "please pay the fee to the front desk");
                                UserPanel u = new UserPanel();
                                u.Show();
                                this.Hide();
                            }
                            else if (date <= 0)
                            {
                                com = new SqlCommand("delete lend where client_name ='" + comboBox1.Text + "'" +
                                    "UPDATE book_list set book_stock = book_stock  1 WHERE book_name ='" + comboBox1.Text + "'", conn);
                                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                MessageBox.Show("You Returned the book " + date + " Days Late!" +
                                    "please pay the fee to the front desk");
                                UserPanel u = new UserPanel();
                                u.Show();
                                this.Hide();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        conn.Close();
```

You should check for `DBNull` value, if the column is null-able in the database a `DBNull.Value` will be returned instead! So you should check this column for such a value before dealing with it 
Also, you shouldn't accept values from the user input and directly injecting them into the SQL query! `ADO.Net`. Has something called `Sql Parameters` it can be found in the property `Parameters` in the `SqlCommand` class. You should use this property to add values from user as parameters to the query
For Example, client name can be added like this:

```
    com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("client_name", comboBox1.Text));
```

Now you tell the Sql Command that the value is actually presented in the `SqlParameters` collection like this:

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("update lend set date_back=convert(datetime2, getdate(), 102) where client_name ='@client_name'", conn);
```

Take a look at this question [Why do we always prefer using parameters in the SQL statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/why-do-we-always-prefer-using-parameters-in-sql-statements)
This is a [MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx) for the `Parameters` property

Comment: Thanks!! its now running properly, thank you my friend :)

Answer (score 0):

Run code below the answer will be obvious :

```
                string sql1 = "update lend set date_back=convert(datetime2, getdate(), 102) where client_name ='" + comboBox1.Text + "'";
                Console.WriteLine(sql1);
                Console.ReadLine();
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(sql1, conn);
                string sql2 = "Declare @startdate smalldatetime declare @enddate smalldatetime set @startdate = (select date_lended from dbo.lend where client_name = '" + comboBox1.Text + "') set @enddate = (select date_back from dbo.lend where client_name = '" + comboBox1.Text + "') SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, @startdate+2, @enddate)as timepassedd"
                Console.ReadLine();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql2, conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
set @startdate = (select date_lended from dbo.lend where client_name = '" + comboBox1.Text + "')
set @enddate = (select date_back from dbo.lend where client_name = '" + comboBox1.Text + "')
```

a) vulnerable to unexpected behaviour if comboBox1.Text was ever to contain ' characters

b) both will result in @startdate or @enddate being NULL if there are no records matching what's selected in the combobox, which then produces a NULL value for '@datepassedd', hence your error when trying to convert to an int.

c) you don't need to query the database twice, you can just do

```
select DATEDIFF(DAY, date_lended+2, date_back) as timepassedd FROM dbo.lend where client_name = @clientName
```

(@clientName can then be added a as parameter)

In this case, there will be no rows returned if no records match the name. BTW there was never any need to use a DataTable and iterate through the records, as your query as it is now only ever returns a single row.